# Extracting the Control Flow Graph from the gcc output

Tags: gcc, assembly, control-flow-graph

I am trying to extract the Control Flow Graph from the assembly code that gcc produces. I have manage to dump the CFG of several IRs (rtl phases) into .vcg files using the arguments -fdump-rtl-* and -dv. Is there any way to do the same thing but for the final assembly code? I would like a generic, target-independent and easy to be parsed representation (like vcg representation). My source code is in C language (in case that it plays any important role).

Best regards,
Michalis.

Comment: I am also trying to construct a CFG for a C program. Where can I start from? Any resource are welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Intel PTU and VTune will do it if you can run the app for profiling... not sure if it can generate the graph without having run the code though.  Otherwise you might be looking at something like this: http://compilers.cs.ucla.edu/avrora/cfg.html.